# Function for class exemplar

Tags: python

I have something like that in my python code

```
class A:
  __mess = "Yeap!"
  def doSome(self):
    self.FN()
  def FN(self):
    pass

def myFN(self):
  print self.__mess

b = A()
b.FN = myFN
b.doSome()
```

But this doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

python 2.6.5

upd: I want to redefine method (FN) only for one exemplar (b).

upd2:

```
import new
class A:
  __mess = "Yeap!"
  def doSome(self):
    self.FN()
  def FN(self):
    pass

def myFN(self):
  print self.__mess

b = A()
b.FN = new.instancemethod(myFN, b, A)
b.doSome()
```

Doesn't work too.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "", line 4, in doSome
>   File "", line 2, in myFN
>   AttributeError: A instance has no
>   attribute '__mess'

Comment: looks like an infinite loop, at least at first glance.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @townsean: He probably wants it to loop infinitely, not exit with a type error. @Ximik: If you get an error, you should always post the error message, not just say "It doesn't work". Say what you would expect to happen, and what happens instead. Don't make us to guess where the problems are.

Comment: @townsean I'm writting a daemon, so there is infinite loop. But this is really superfluous thing in example. So I changed the post a bit.
@sth ok, thank for advice. I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myLoopFN` is a function, not an instance method. Do

```
import new
b.loopFN = new.instancemethod( myLoopFN, b, A )
```

The problem is that Python treats instance methods very slightly differently to regular functions: they get the instance upon which they are run as the default first argument. If you define a method inside a class definition it automagically becomes an instance method, so that when you instantiate the class it gets passed the instance. However, when you define `myLoopFN` you do it *outside* the class definition, so that it is an ordinary function instead of an instance method. You fix this by explicitly declaring it as an instance method.

...

### BUT

This is icky because it's **not something you should do**; changing instance methods at runtime will lead to problems. You'll never be sure whether your `A` is an original `A` or a modified one, and you won't be able to debug it because you can't tell whether you've changed `loopFN` or not. This will give you the kind of bugs that [Nyarlathotep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyarlathotep) himself would be proud of.

The *right* way to do this is to subclass `A` and override the method, so that you can distinguish between the different classes.

```
class myA( A ):
    def loopFN(self):
        #put modified function here
```

This way, you can instantiate the modified class and be certain of its methods.

#### Edit

You are using a double-underscore variable name, `__mess`. You (almost certainly) don't want to do this. For some reason known only to our Benevolent Dictator for Life and a select few others, Python automatically mangles these `__` names to `_<class-name>__`, to serve as a sort-of faux private variable. This is horrible, and besides there's no reason to call it `__mess` instead of (the much nicer) `mess`.

If you *absolutely must* call it `__mess`, you can refer to it as follows:

```
def myFN(self):
    print( self._A__mess )
```

(mutatis mutandis when you change the name of A). This is nasty and unPythonic.

Comment: Please, look at upd2. Seems like it doesn't work too.

Subclassing seems overweightly for this code. In Ruby this is standart code-style (maybe I'm wrong, don't use it for a long time).

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that you were using double-underscore variable names. The short answer is, don't use them. Python will mangle `__mess` into `_A__mess`, as a faux-private variable. There's no reason to call it anything but `mess`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second error (with `__mess`):

Change

```
print self.__mess
```

to

```
print self._mess
```

And change

```
class A:
  __mess = "Yeap!"
```

to

```
class A:
  _mess = "Yeap!"
```

Double underscores tell Python to use [name-mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).

An alternative is to change

```
def myFN(self):
    print self.__mess
```

to

```
def myFN(self):
    print self._A__mess
```

Comment: oh sorry, didn't notice. Thank you.

Comment: @Ximik: Not a problem. It's hard to refresh frequently enough when everyone's posting :)